# Properly identifying enums with same underlying value

Tags: c#, enums

Assume I have this `enum` defined, where several members have the same underlying value:

```
enum Number
{
  One = 1,
  Eins = 1,
  Uno = 1
}
```

According to [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw.aspx):

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.

So for example,

```
var number = Number.One;
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

gives me the following output:

> Eins

Printing all enum members,

```
Console.WriteLine($"{Number.One} {Number.Eins} {Number.Uno}");
```

yields the following output:

> Eins Eins Eins

However, taking the `nameof` of each member,

```
Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(Number.One)} {nameof(Number.Eins)} {nameof(Number.Uno)}");
```

gives the following result:

> One Eins Uno

So apparently the `enum` members *are* separable. Can I take advantage of this separation, i.e. is there *any* way I can assign a specific `Number` member to a variable and consistently have that *same* member returned whenever the variable is accessed?

Comment: Why are you in this situation to begin with?

Comment: Legacy code....

Comment: Looks like a good place to get rid f the Enum and use globalization / resource files.

Comment: Not totally sure what you want to do? Could you give a pseudo example of what you would like to do?

Comment: OK, maybe I shouldn't have used different languages in the example. My issue has nothing to do with internationalization.

Comment: I would say no, because only the `nameof` function is going to look-up the actual name. In normal circumstances the `Number` value will be `1` and will return the first(?) enum that matches it.

Comment: @FSDaniel I already know of alternative solution paths if I cannot make anything sensible out of the *same underlying value* issue. I only would like to have a relevant answer to the question itself.

Comment: If you are casting the variable to the underlying type (int) you would not be able, otherwise, you could have a look to Enum.GetNames(Type) function

Comment: It's still not entirely clear to me what your end goal is. What is the end result you are trying to achieve and why? Maybe that will help us think of a better alternative. An example with some expected input and then expected output or side affect based on that input might help too.

Comment: Thanks, @Igor, but right now I am only interested in relevant (and ideally positive) answers to this question.

Comment: : enum Number
{
  One = 1,
  Eins = One,
  Uno = One,
}

Comment: @AndersGustafsson, sorry for being unclear. I would like to give you an answer and not another solution but i am just not sure what code you would like to write. When you say " is there any way I can assign a specific Number member..." what do you mean by that? Do you want to send in an int with value 1 and always get back the enum Eins all the time and then be able to switch that so you suddenly get One instead? Just not sure what you want. If I am still unclear just ignore this :)

Comment: I think the OP wants to assign `Number.One` and always get `Number.One` back. But it resolves to `Number.Eins` because it shares `1`

Comment: @FSDaniel I am sorry for being dismissive in the previous comment. I am only concerned about the cases where I have explicitly assigned a specific member to a variable, e.g. `var number = Number.One`. In those scenarios I want to be sure that when I access `number` I will always get `Number.One` back. As pointed out in Sweeper's answer below, this does not seem to be possible though, so it looks like I need to rely on another solution.

Comment: You could create a 2nd `enum` next to your first with the same types but limit the members to those that you expect (and make sure there are no shared values). Then you can cast from one to the other and use the new enum in your refactored code that relies on specific/expected members.

Comment: Thanks, @Igor, that's a thought. I do think it makes the code overly complex and brittle though. Wouldn't it be nice to be able to subclass enums instead? :-)

Comment: @AndersGustafsson - when you are stuck with legacy code options can sometimes be limited unless you have the resources to refactor and implement something correctly (*usually not the case though*).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So apparently the `enum` members *are* separable

Well, that's not entirely true... They are only separable at compile time.

You see, `nameof` is actually an expression evaluated at compile time. It is a constant expression. This can be proved by assigning a `nameof` expression to a `const`:

```
const string a = nameof(Number.One);
```

It compiles.

Trying to get the string representation of a enum value using string interpolation on the other hand, is evaluated at runtime, so this does not compile:

```
const string a = $"{Number.One}";
```

At runtime, the enum cases are not separable, so the answer to:

> is there any way I can assign a specific Number member to a variable and consistently have that same member returned whenever the variable is accessed?

is "no".

Comment: I will keep you in suspense a while longer, in case someone else wants to answer too :-)

Answer (score 2):

The only possibility I see to always return an expected enum name is to create a 2nd `enum` next to your first of the underlying type and with the same values but limit the members to those that you expect (*and make sure there are no shared values*). Then you can cast from one to the other and use the new enum in your refactored code that relies on specific/expected members.

**SomeMethod**

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:G}", (KnownNumber)Number.Eins); // > One
Console.WriteLine("{0:G}", (KnownNumber)Number.Uno); // > One
Console.WriteLine("{0:G}", (KnownNumber)Number.One); // > One
```

**Enums.cs**

```
public enum Number
{
  One = 1,
  Eins = 1,
  Uno = 1
}

public enum KnownNumber
{
  One = 1,
  Two = 2,
  Three = 3
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gjzTzh)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something that should get it work

```
public static class NumberExtension
{
    private static Dictionary<int, string> pointers = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    public static unsafe void SetValue(this Number source, string value)
    {
        if (pointers.ContainsKey((int)&source))
            pointers[(int)&source] = value;
        else
            pointers.Add((int)&source, value);
    }
    public static unsafe string GetValue(this Number source)
    {
        if (pointers.ContainsKey((int)&source))
            return pointers[(int)&source];
        return source.ToString();
    }
}
```

And to use:

```
    Number num = default(Number);
    num.SetValue(nameof(Number.Uno));
    Console.WriteLine(num.GetValue());
```

However, it looks like a kind of 'hack' and I do NOT recommend it. It would be better if you look for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, Aly. As you state yourself though, this is too much of a "hack" for my needs, so I'd rather consider refactoring instead.